# Getting text from a Listview

Tags: android

I have a ListView that gets filled from a cursor (using rawQuery) that I need to get the text of the selected item from on click.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent mViewChaptersIntent = new Intent(this, ViewWeb.class);
    String s = ((TextView) l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getText().toString(); // Tried this, didn't work.
    mViewChaptersIntent.putExtra("extension", s);
    mViewChaptersIntent.putExtra("itmClicked", String.format("%d", id));
    startActivity(mViewChaptersIntent);
}
```

But I'm not sure about the right way to do it. The getItemAtPosition that I've seen in other posts doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getItemAtPosition()` should return you a `Cursor` that is positioned at the specified row. You will then need to call `getString()` to retrieve whatever column you are looking for.

Comment: That seemed to do it.
For future reference: `String s = (String)((Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getString(2);`

Comment: How could be any faster without generics?